# How to right align text in a subsection?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning

I want to right-align part of a subsection, but I am getting the error message: ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Here is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\subsection{\textbf{University}}

\subsubsection{B.S. in Major \begin{flushright} Anticipated, 2023 \end{flushright}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure about that? With that code, I don't get any error. Not even a warning.

Comment: To me it looks like you are trying to craft a title page. For this, it is better to use the `titlepage` environment, or adapt the `\maketitle` command. See e.g. [the explanations on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_5):_Customising_Your_Title_Page_and_Abstract)

Answer (score 1):

Rather set the elements using `\hfill` since `flushright` is meant for paragraph text (it actually sets a *list*, hence your "missing `\item`" error). Note that arguments for sectional units do move, as it ends up in the ToC and may be influenced by certain packages. So, use

```
\subsubsection{B.Sc.\ in Major \hfill Anticipated, 2023}
```

or possibly

```
\subsubsection[B.Sc.\ in Major]{B.Sc.\ in Major \hfill Anticipated, 2023}
```

if you plan on using the moving arguments.